# Printing a string in Excel VBA after selecting multiple checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using a userform on excel VBA to enter data into a different sheet but I have not found a way to concatenate multiple values together and put a comma in between each input. An example using the attached picture would be if Dusty Dry and Static were all selected the value that would be entered into the cell would be "Dusty, Dry, Static". Is there a way to do something like:

```
Range("R4").Value = If Dusty.Value = true then "Dusty"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Range("R4").Value = iif(dusty, "Dusty ", "") & _
                    iif(dry, "Dry ", "") & _
                    iif(damp, "Damp", "") & _
                    iif(static, "Static", "") & _
                    iif(abrasive, "Abrasive ", "") & _
                    iif(cohesive, "Cohesive ", "") & _
                    iif(hygroscopic, "Hygroscopic ", "") & _
                    iif(friable, "Friable ", ""))
Range("R4").Value = application.trim(Range("R4").Value)
Range("R4").Value = replace(Range("R4").Value, " ", ", ")
```

Comment: Thank you!! I believe that is exactly what I needed I am going to use it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

```
If Dusty Then Range("R4") = "Dusty"
```

Which is short for:

```
If Dusty.Value = True Then 
    Range("R4").Value = "Dusty"
End If
```

For multiple checkboxes, something like this per checkbox should be ok:

```
If Dusty Then Range("R4") = Range("R4") & "Dusty" & vbCrLf
If Friable Then Range("R4") = Range("R4") & "Friable" & vbCrLf
```

It concatenates the values of the `Range("R4")` with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve this by looping through all of the controls on the form. Some of the benefits to this approach would be that you can add more checkboxes without having to modify the code, it's significantly less characters of code than the other approaches, and there is no redundant code (e.g. repeated used of `iif()` with different parameters).

The main drawback to this approach would be if you wanted the values in a sorted order. They will be sorted in the order in which the CheckBoxes were created.

Another consideration is if you have other CheckBox controls on the form you don't want this to apply to. You could add an additional check to look for a prefix on the `.Name` property, or set something in `.Tag` property, or put the CheckBoxes inside of a frame and change `Me.Controls` to `Frame1.Controls`.

```
Dim Control As Control, Data As String
For Each Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(Control) = "CheckBox" Then
        If Control.Value Then ' This is on a different line to prevent errors, VB checks all conditions of an If even if first one is false. 
            Data = Iif(Data <> "",Data & ", ","") & Control.Caption
        End If
    End If
Next

Range("R4").Value = Data
```

Notice how I used an `Iif()` to update `Data` for your concern about separating the values with a comma.